# Check if two lists have any element in common

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add to `list1` element(s) from `list2` where value for `type` key is not the same?

```dart
  var list1 = <Map<String, String>>[
    {'id': '123', 'type': 'START', 'location': 'Vienna'},
  ];

  var list2 = <Map<String, String>>[
    {'type': 'START'},
    {'type': 'STOPOVER'},
    {'type': 'DESTINATION'},
    {'type': 'END'}
  ];
```

So `list1` should look like this at the end:

```dart
  list1 = <Map<String, String>>[
    {'id': '123', 'type': 'START', 'location': 'Vienna'},
    {'type': 'STOPOVER'},
    {'type': 'DESTINATION'},
    {'type': 'END'}
  ];
```

Comment: Where `type` is not the same? But the result added seems like where `type` is the same.

Comment: Whart did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Can you insert into your list? Can you query your list? Can you combine those two?

Comment: @Josteve Sorry, maybe I didn't formulate the question properly. As you can see at the beginning `list1` has 1 entry, at the end 4. `'type': 'START'` was a match in both lists so it should just skip it,  `{'type': 'STOPOVER'}, {'type': 'DESTINATION'}, {'type': 'END'}` was not present in the list1 so it should add them. Is it better now?
@nvoigt I have tried with `any` and `contains`, was trying to use `where` but I could not get the syntax right. I could also create the 3rd list and combine them, any approach would be acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a more imperative style:

```
var result = <Map<String, String>>[];

for (var x2 in list2) {
    final x1s_like_x2 = list1.where((x1) => x1['type'] == x2['type']);
    if (x1s_like_x2.isEmpty) {
        result.add(x2);
    } else {
        result.addAll(x1s_like_x2);
    }
}
```

Then you'll have the merged list in `result`.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.addAll(
    list2.where((item) => list1.where((item2) => item['type'] != item2['type']).isNotEmpty)
);
```